# Enumerating relations that are true infinitely often

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, computability

Let us concentrate on relations on natural numbers. Is it possible to enumerate all computable unary relations that are true infinitely often? I would guess no but I can't see a direct way to prove it.

Comment: Do you mean *effectively* enumerate?

Comment: Given the axiom of choice, every set is enumerable. By machinery, if you mean algorithm as formalized by Turing machines, then you mean effective or computable enumeration. Then this is not possible. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that unary relations on the natural numbers are just sets. So computable unary relations are just computable sets. Each computable enumerable set has an index which is a natural number. Let $W_e$ denote the $e^\text{th}$ computable enumerable set.

Let $A = \{e : W_e \text{ is computable and } W_e \text{ is infinite }\}$. Now let us suppose that $A$ is computably enumerable.

Let $\Phi_e$ denote the $e^\text{th}$ Turing machine. $\bar{H} = \{e : \Phi_e(e) \text{ does not halt }\}$. It is well known that the halting problem is a computable enumerable incomputable set. Hence the complement $\bar{H}$ is not computably enumerable.

Now for each $e$. Let $S_e = \{s : \Phi_e(e) \text{ has not halted in $s$ steps }\}$. Note that $S_e$ is always computable since $S_e$ is either finite or all of the natural numbers. Because the process defined above is computable uniformly, there is a computable function $f$ such that $S_e = W_{f(e)}$. Hence if $\Phi_e(e)$ does not converges, then $S_e = W_{f(e)} = \omega$ is infinite. If $\Phi_e(e)$ does converge then, $S_e$ is finite.

So the $f$ above is a computable reduction of $\bar{H}$ to $A$. Since we assumed that $A$ is computable enumerable, this means that $\bar{H}$ is also computably enumerable. But this contradicts the well-known fact that $\bar{H}$ is not computably enumerable.

Comment: The OP may also find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem of interest.